# TypeError: undefined is not a function zclip

Tags: jquery, drupal, zclip

I am including the required files then calling zclip with this code, I tried moving the order of js files around and including in footer but not working.  I get this error when i try to run this code in firebug console as a test.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

this tells me that the zclip javascript file is not working, I am running drupal 7 with jquery 1.4.4

```
$('a.tocopy').zclip({
        path:'/sites/all/themes/my_theme/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('#mini-panel-track_node_assets .view .view-content').text()
    });
$('a.tocopy').zclip({
        path:'/sites/all/themes/my_theme/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy:$('#mini-panel-track_node_assets .view .view-content').text()
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because `zclip` function is not loaded and jQuery does not know the function. first load jQuery and then load the plugin.

Comment: it is loaded it is included on the page,i am loading scripts in correct order

Answer (score -1):

Сhange line 288:

```
$(this.domElement).data('zclipId', 'zclip-' + this.movieId);
```

to

```
jQuery(this.domElement).data('zclipId', 'zclip-' + this.movieId);
```

upd: now it's fixed: https://github.com/patricklodder/jquery-zclip/blob/master/jquery.zclip.js line 296: